# Is there any phrase like "with the idea of"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is there any phrase like "with the idea of"

> ***with the idea of*** reducing the complexities, we introduce an added
>   smoothing step.

I was googling to find example usages, but couldn't. so please any one give some alternatives if this phrase is not valid.

some synonim phrases are also welcome to learn. thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *with the idea of* but you could also use *in the name of* or *with the aim of*. With a little reformulating you can say things like *in order to* or *so that we can*

Comment: I'm curious as to what Google queries you ran when you tried to find examples (that might save me from making the same fruitless searches). Also, given that this is a site for **serious language enthusiasts**, while you're amending your question, you might want to use proper capitalization, too, and maybe even copy-and-paste your question into some application that will do some spell checking for you.

Comment: @J.R.: nothing special... simply by typing in Google " usage of with the idea of".

Comment: _To reduce the complexities, we introduce an added smoothing step._

If you're not certain that this will work, use hedging: 

_In an attempt to reduce the complexities, we introduce an added smoothing step._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I think you're right - plain *"**to**"* is by far the best alternative. Anything else is just pointless verbal padding.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

> *With an eye toward* reducing complexities, we added a smoothing step.

In this case, *with an eye toward* means "for the purposes of."

Merriam-Webster defines ["with an eye toward" or "with an eye to"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye) as:

> 1. with awareness or contemplation of - *with an eye to the future*
> 2. with the object of - *built the house with an eye to adding on later*

Here are a couple of links showing the phrase being used:

> [Prizes With an Eye Toward the Future](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/02/29/prizes-with-an-eye-toward-the-future/)
>
> [Documenting Social Ills With an Eye Toward Advocacy](http://www.nieman.harvard.edu/reports/article/101604/Documenting-Social-Ills-With-an-Eye-Toward-Advocacy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for familiar as opposed to contrived phrases...

- with the view to
- after a fashion...
- with similar purpose as/of
- accordingly as
- (and such depending...)

Is it just that you are trying to avoid phrase repetition? Just curious.

Comment: of course, i want to avoid repetition too

Comment: Apart from *with the view to* (which in fact is invariably *with **a** view to*), I don't think any of these alternatives could be used in OP's context. In fact, I think most of them couldn't be used in *any* context, since they're not "standard English".

Comment: @TimLymington: The daft thing is I would have *upvoted* this one when I read the first suggestion (and leave a comment pointing out that "a" is more common than "the"). But the baby went out with the bathwater, I'm afraid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ha haa..didnt get ur last saying

Comment: @niro: Perhaps we English speakers don't see things the same as the rest of the world. To us, the *baby* is what you want to keep, and the (dirty) *bathwater* is what you want to throw away. It's generally considered a ***bad thing*** if [Your baby has gone down the plug hole](http://www.metrolyrics.com/mothers-lament-lyrics-cream.html).